# QT variable assignment, <no such value>, SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, qt

I've got 3 clases, every one have 3 variables of int type. Also 3 member functions in which I try to assign those variables to dynamic array and return the array. In first case every thing is fine, problems apears when i try to assign variables from second and the third class.

```
#ifndef TANK_H
#define TANK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

class Tank : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Tank(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void setTanks(int x, int y, QGraphicsScene * scene);
    void addTanks(int howMany = 0);
    int * showStatisticsOfTank();

protected:
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    int coordinateX, coordinateY;

    int amountOfTanks;
    int attack;
    int defence;
    int cost;
signals:
public slots:
};

#endif // TANK_H
```

In .cpp file:

```
int *Tank::showStatisticsOfTank()
{
    int * arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = amountOfTanks;
    arr[1] = attack;
    arr[2] = defence;
    return arr;
}
```

This works...
But:

```
#ifndef WARPLANE_H
#define WARPLANE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

class Warplane : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Warplane(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void setWarplane(int x, int y, QGraphicsScene * scene);
    void addWarplane(int howMany = 0);
    int * showStatisticOfWarplane();

protected:
    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    int coordinateX, coordinateY;

    int amountOfWarplanes;
    int attack;
    int defence;
    int cost;
signals:  
public slots:
};

#endif // WARPLANE_H
```

In .cpp file:

```
int *Warplane::showStatisticOfWarplane()
{
    int * arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = amountOfWarplanes; //HERE ERROR SHOWS UP
    arr[1] = attack;
    arr[3] = defence;
    return arr;
}
```

This doesn't... The SIGSEGV error shows up and debugger stops at this line. When I'm trying to look what value is in the amountOfWarplanes,attack and defence it says:

```
<no such value>.
```

The third class is pretty the same, and when I comment out the second class error apears in third class in the same spot. I tried to clean all -> rebuild, doesn't works.

Comment: Your array has 3 elements not 4, you are reading element out of range in this line `arr[3] = defence;`.

Comment: Your `Tank` and `Warplane` classes look identical, at least, API wise. Why don't you use a single class instead?

Comment: @rafix07 it's just typo, I've improve this but the problem is same.

Comment: @vahancho yes they do, but I'm setting to them different graphics, I could create 1 class and inherit from her but, idk you think this will solve the problem ?

Comment: @HappyEnd, my comment was just observation. I didn't mean it will solve the problem, but it definitely may help to avoid such problems. Anyways, you could reconsider your class design.

Comment: The SIGSEGV happens when accessing *this*. Are you sure the Warplane object is valid when you call showStatisticOfWarplane() ? Also, is there any other thread involved in the lifecycle of that object?

Comment: It is really a bad Idea to allocate an array with new and return it outside the class. Nobody knows the ownership of this array and the caller is supposed to delete it later. This is bad design. Return a object or a unique_ptr or shared_ptr at least

Comment: Yea, the problem was that the warplane pointer were not valid... My bad, stupid mistake... @Taron thanks for ideas, I'll try to fix this :)

Comment: @HappyEnd I added my answer, for people who may read your question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SIGSEGV happens when trying to access *amountOfWarplanes* which is an internal member of the class **Warplane**. This means it happens while trying to access **this**.

These conditions suggest that the Warplane pointer is invalid.